# href link executes javascript before go to links

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('a').click(function(){
  //Do something
  return false;
});
```

I have a links when user click, I want to run some javascript, after script complete, I want it go to next page.

I put return false to prevent it goes next page before script finish, however this will disable href go to next page.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can `prevent false` and manually go:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;

    //code

    location.href = href;
});
```

Comment: How is the behavior of this any different than the original code? I think the insight OP needs is that `location.href` probably needs to be set by some callback.

Comment: His code will nav away...I'm just saying execute the href at the end if you want to execute the JS first.

Answer (score 0):

you can manually put your link

```
    window.location=" ../yourlink";
```